# Why is that happening (Pushing UIViews Related)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using in each UIView

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

so i can see the Window background image

When I'm pushing views over each other some weird glitches are appearing like this:

[Uploaded the video on youtube here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHqcSrkP6Ag&feature=youtu.be)

How can I take them out ?

Comment: Are you using any non-standard code to navigate views?

Comment: no I'm using [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewController animated:YES]; (Updated the question for more info)

Comment: Here is what I think is happening. It looks like the incoming view, which has a clear background color to begin with, shows the view underneath. I'm going to assume that's the glitch you're talking about. Instead of setting the background color to be clear right away, you might want to wait and do it in the viewDidAppear() method. I don't think this gets called until the view is fully on the screen.

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth your solution may did some trick but now the view appears with white backgoundcolor then it is set to clear which is not appealing at all any other solution ?

Comment: Why dont you try    
 `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[windows background image]];` or you've tried this already? okay bye, i think you already knew the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember

> Only solution to this problem, never set background color of main view
>   to clear color.

As your next view coming over the previous view, if you set background to clear color, means it is transparent, the previous view is always visible for sometime which spoil animation.

I had this problem, and it was because of old code in the pushed view controller, which caused the view to "fade in", setting the alpha to 0 on viewWillAppear and setting the alpha to 1 on viewDidAppear.

I removed the old code that did this, and the push worked fine.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
    self.view.alpha = 0; //REMOVE THIS LINE
}
```

If you try ,you will find this DID NOT happen on iOS 6, but as soon as I started using iOS 7 as the base SDK in Xcode 5 or later, this started happening.